# How much can I hold without any containers?

Tags: dnd-5e, encumbrance, weight

How much gear can you hold with out a backpack or any container?
If your a fighter and pick leather armor, longbow, twenty arrows, rapier, shield, two handaxe, and an explore's pack. wear the armor and the pack, hold the sword and shield, tuck the handaxes in your pants, loop the bow around your torso, stick eight arrows between your toes two up your nose and ten in your mouth. So you can hold all that sure but you can't do anything.

Do you even need containers?

Comment: I take it this is not a carry weight question and is more about inventory logistics? You have it tagged as weight, but it seems more about volume storage and containers.

Comment: You've asked a few questions here, some of which need to be their own question. For example, "don't you need to use interact if you don't have a quiver" should be it's own. We try to have posts focus on 1 question at a time.

Comment: Are you coming to D&D recently, but have played a number of video games?

Comment: Yes but I don't play RPGs at much.

Comment: Could you clarify your actual problem here? You ask what you can hold without any containers or what's the point... but I think your question both illustrates what you can hold *and* what the point is, and it looks like you're fully aware of both of those things: *"So you can hold all that sure but you can't do anything."*  So what problem is left over here? What's your difficulty or point of confusion?

Comment: The reason I ask is that you seem to be attempting something that adds unnecessary complication to the game.  What's the problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: if i don't have a backpack, quiver, chest, mount, or any container, how much stuff can I have assuming the weight limit isn't a problem?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question with a straightforward answer.

Comment: Hi Nathan, and welcome to the site. This post seems to have some interesting things in it (based on the comment-engagement I'm seeing from some long-time users) but also some sticky points (based on the hold-votes from some long-time users). I just wanted to mention that I've thrown an upvote your way to help facilitate NautArch's invitation to [chat]--20 reputation points are required to participate in chat rooms and you're almost there. If you want to make use of that resource, there are people there with experience in the site and interest in your question!

Comment: @NathanSantee Guildsbounty is referencing [that we do not answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments). So, it is not the job of comments here to provide what the answer is. If and when this question is deemed reopenable (including after revisions if necessary), and enough people vote to reopen it, then it will receive answers. These comments are also not for debating or discussing the topic at length: their focus is to clarify your question so that it can be reopened.

Comment: Note: the explorer's pack is a backpack containing adventuring gear (bedroll, cooking kit, tinderbox, etc) Thus, a container.

Comment: but its full so i can't put my heavy crossbow, longbow, shield, 2 short swords, hunters traps, or any of my outer stuff

Comment: @NathanSantee Yeah but you're asking us how much you can carry without containers, including without a backpack, but we're asked to work with a scenario which involves full use of a backpack. This doesn't make a lot of sense for us to be able to answer reasonably.

Comment: I have 30 lbs of gear in my backpack, 2.5 lbs of cases with bolts in them and 480 on my horse. So how much can more can I take now that I have used all my containers?

Comment: @NathanSantee doesn't your questions already describe a potential upper bound: "So you can hold all that sure but you can't do anything." What "anything" do you suppose you can't do?

Comment: Some guidance to help this question reopen: Provide a clear question that you want answered (i.e. "Can I carry <list of things> without a container even though this doesn't exceed my encumbrance limit?" or "Do the encumbrance rules require me to use containers once weight exceeds a certain point?"); providing more information than might be necessary can be helpful (i.e. what's your strength score and class level?); identify sections of the rules that you've looked at already and discuss how they relate to your question (i.e. encumbrance rules in the PHB don't seem to address containers).

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?) on [Do PCs have a volumetric carry capacity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116950/do-pcs-have-a-volumetric-carry-capacity-limit)

Comment: do I need containers?

Comment: @NathanSantee You might be better served in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)

Comment: i don't know how to switch between this and chat

Comment: @NathanSantee Click on this link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat